# Material UI Card box-shadow being cut off

Tags: javascript, css, material-ui

While using Material UI's Card. I am having an issue I do not usually have.
box-shadow that is being cut off on the bottom and top hand side..

How can i fix this?

**My code here**:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './demo.css'
import { Card } from '@material-ui/core';


export default class MasonryLayout extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="masonry">
        <Card className="item" style={{height:"120px"}} elevation={4}/>
        <Card className="item" style={{height:"190px"}} elevation={4}/>
        <Card className="item" style={{height:"220px"}} elevation={4}/>
        <Card className="item" style={{height:"130px"}} elevation={4}/>
        <Card className="item" style={{height:"140px"}} elevation={4}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

```css
.masonry {
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 56px;
    margin: 50px;
}

.item {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    break-inside: avoid;
}
```

**screenshot blew**:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvXgd.png)

Comment: Add some minimum height to CardWrapper as not much information is not given. If not works, share your html code or working example.

Comment: Thx for your help. I have added min-height to CardsWrapper. but it not works.  I wrote a demo, and paste the code on top.

Comment: Not able to see live example. Could you please share your live code somewhere so that I can check live.

Comment: Material typically use the `overflow` property, Add `overflow: visible`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I solved it by adding the "**ENOUGH**" margin to the bottom/side.

**NOTE**
Just adding 1-2 px is not enough depending on your elevation. For me I had to add m={1.25} for elevation 5. If you add only a small amount of margin, it the shadows do not look natural and will look like a shadow in a box. You just need to add more margin to make it look as anticipated.